# Getting the details of the current song playing in the media player in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm currently using a method similar to the one below to retrieve the information, however I am not sure how I can obtain the genre. Does anyone know what the string extra is called for genre or if there is an extra at all? Thanks.

[Track info of currently playing music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510292/how-to-get-current-music-track-info)

```
public class CurrentMusicTrackInfoActivity extends Activity 
{

 public static final String SERVICECMD = "com.android.music.musicservicecommand";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);



com.sec.android.app.music.player.service.CorePlayerService

IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");





registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
String action = intent.getAction();
String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
Log.v("tag ", action + " / " + cmd);
String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
Log.v("tag",artist+":"+album+":"+track);
Toast.makeText(CurrentMusicTrackInfoActivity.this,track,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
};

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with similar method? Show us your code thusfar.

Comment: I mean similar to the code in the link provided. I've edited it now to show the code.

Comment: Try running Intent app in marketplace and see whats being passed around.

Comment: There is a free intent app that will publish what is being sent around in intents during an application run.

Comment: Thanks, would you happen to know the name of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out there is no genre extra passed, just the 3 above and id. I was able to see the extras passed using the following code:

```
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        Set<String> set = b.keySet();
        Iterator it = set.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()==true){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+it.next(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```