# android-how to get background music of other app

Tags: android, background-music, getstate

First,I'm trying to do a music plug-in.

Then,the app need acquire state of other app's background music (**playing** or **pause/stop**).

```
1.If other app's background music is play ,then my plug-in not do anything.

2.If the background music is pause/stop,then my plug-in will have some operation.
```

I have seached a lot about the android music.but I have find the way to get current state of music play.I can only get `isActive`.but this method whether on **play** or  **pause**  ,the return value are same:`true`.that make me craze for one week.

then i try otherway but in the upper layer the player are control by mediaplay,which i can get the class object from.

So could anyone tell me is there a way that can tell the music play state? thanks for your any help.

Comment: well.is someone save me here?

Comment: Try listening for metadata change broadcasts, Here's [how-to-get-current-music-track-info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510292/how-to-get-current-music-track-info), may help.

Comment: @javee i try this but nothing happen. i'm wondering if the `unity3d`doesn't send any broadcast to android?