# How to get "cover/artwork" of song currently played?

Tags: android, android-music-player, artwork

I'm grabbing the current song-details of the several media-players in Android with that [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510292/how-to-get-current-music-track-info):

```
IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
...
registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
```

For track, album, author etc. it works fine, but now I also want to get the cover-art/artwork to display that at another position.

Has anyone an idea where I can find that informations? They seem to be not provided in the Intent-extras.

Comment: Use [`MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.AlbumArt`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.html#ALBUM_ART). The docs aren't clear what type of data you'll get from it, but it's at least a start.

Comment: Thanks you David, that's a beginning :)