# Get info about audio, playing in another application

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

How can i get info about source (filedesc. or uri) from which another application playing audio?

In AudioManager there is only isMusicActive() method, which doesn't give any additional information.
And because of it isn't my application, i doesn't have any MediaPlayer object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Register a broadcast receiver for known action intents and handle the broadcast to show or do something with the track information, [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510292/track-info-of-currently-playing-music):

```
public class CurrentMusicTrackInfoActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String SERVICECMD = "com.android.music.musicservicecommand";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");
        iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");     
        iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");        
        iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
            Log.v("tag ", action + " / " + cmd);
            String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
            String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
            String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
            Log.v("tag", artist + ":" + album + ":" + track);
            Toast.makeText(CurrentMusicTrackInfoActivity.this, track, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it's what i searching for!

Comment: This solution is good enough for me. But have one more additional question. If music start play first, and then i start this application, is there possibility to get some info (maybe some sticky intent) with data about currently playing song?

Comment: how can we get the album art of the currently playing song?

Comment: did you find any solution for Album art yet?