# Get Audio File of Song from Google Play Music in Android Development

Tags: android, audio, google-music

I am trying to make a music player app, and I want to get the file of a song that the user selects in my app from their Google Play Music library. Is there any way I can do this? If not, is there a way to detect a song they are playing in the background, possibly from a different app, and then grab that audio file?

Comment: sample code required to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to detect a song they are playing in the background

Yes there is a way.

For simple check whether music is playing or not. Use

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(manager.isMusicActive())
 {
     // Something is being played.
 }
```

And for getting info of songs playing in other app

```
public class CurrentMusicTrackInfoActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String SERVICECMD = "com.android.music.musicservicecommand";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");
        iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");     
        iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");        
        iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
            Log.v("tag ", action + " / " + cmd);
            String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
            String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
            String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
            Log.v("tag", artist + ":" + album + ":" + track);
            Toast.makeText(CurrentMusicTrackInfoActivity.this, track, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

}
```

[**For details.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22247257/3496570)