# Resume music from another android app

Tags: android

I have an app that runs the Youtube API and plays a video in a certain view. When the video plays, the music from any background apps are paused.  I've tried to resume the music with the following code which is run onBackPressed():

```
    private void resumeMusic() {
    if(wasMusicPlaying){
        Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
        i.putExtra("command", "play");
        ExerciseViewer.this.sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

When I go back, I can't get the music to resume.  I know its possible because when using snapchat, the background music automatically resumes after a snap video finishes playing but I can't seem to get this functionality on my app.

I've also tried to use "togglepause" instead of play but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but I think this can be achieved using **Android - MediaPlayer**.
When entering to your app at the begining of the code, you can check audio is playing. (this should done before calling to youtube api)

```
mediaPlayer.isPlaying()
```

if true, you know that a media was playing when someone enter into your application. Store that in your application logic. maybe call it boolean wasplaying,

```
boolean wasPlaying = mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
```

when exiting your application, check whether there's was an any audio playing. if any audio is playing, resume it.

```
if(wasPlaying){
     mediaPlayer.start(); //resumes mediaplayer audio
}
```

I'm not sure about the code and media player does the exact thing, but you can try to use a logic like that.

You can have a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

if mediaplayer doesn't work getting the current playing audio, this would help [Track info of currently playing music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510292/track-info-of-currently-playing-music)