# how to get current playing music details?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510292/track-info-of-currently-playing-music) but I can't get the track details... How to get the current playing track details in android? Is there any way to get current music info?

I used this code but I can't get track info:

```
public class CurrentMusicTrackInfoActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String SERVICECMD = com.android.music.musicservicecommand";

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.playstatechanged");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.playbackcomplete");
        iF.addAction("com.android.music.queuechanged");

        registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
            Log.v("tag ", action + " / " + cmd);
            String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
            String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
            String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
            Log.v("tag", artist + ":" + album + ":" + track);
            Toast.makeText(CurrentMusicTrackInfoActivity.this, track, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

}
```

Comment: `current playing track` in which app does it play?

Comment: can you give me your mail id..@ Vladyslav Matviienko

Comment: No for sure, you have to describe all details here

Comment: usually, every mediaplayer instance has a unique id. if you get this id (dont really know how, but should not be much of a hassle) just instantiate the media player with said id and then read from its properties.